# Expected Value of an expression including error function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expected-value

I want to calculate the expected value to the solution of a Fokker-Plank equation, so one of the terms I got includes the complementary error function, namely: 
$$p(x,t|x_{0},t_{0})=\frac{B}{2 D}*e^{\frac{-Bx}{D}} * \text{erfc}\left(\frac{x+x_{0}-Bt}{2\sqrt{Dt}}\right)$$

So my question is, while calculating the intergral $$E(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x p(x,t|x_{0},t_0)$$

So I would like to know how to get around this integral? Is there some numerical way to calculate it, or is there even some analytical way to find it?

And of course my complementary error function is defined as: 
$$\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x+x_{0}-Bt}{2\sqrt{Dt}}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\frac{x+x_{0}-Bt}{2\sqrt{Dt}}}^{\infty} e^{-z^2} dz $$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the integral for $E(x)$, what is the integration variable ($x, t, x_0$, or $t_0$)?